# Set custom font for Android fragments

Tags: android, fonts, android-fragments

I have been using [Jake Wharton's ViewPagerIndicator](https://github.com/JakeWharton/Android-ViewPagerIndicator) and I am currently trying to implement a custom font on one of my fragments. I've tried using this code:

```
   TextView txt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.Zipcode);
    Typeface font = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "fonts/customfont.ttf");
    txt.setTypeface(font);
```

In the `onCreate` for the main activity which results in a null pointer exception in logcat and occasionally `typeface cannot be made`. I've also tried to set the font in the fragment itself in both the `onCreate` and `onCreateView` however `findViewById` and `getAssests()` are unknown methods in the fragment scope.

I'm having trouble figuring out if the font is the problem or where I am trying to set the fon't is the problem.

Comment: Is `customfont.ttf` in `assets/fonts/`?

Comment: @kcoppock correct I have it in assets/fonts

Answer (score 60, accepted):

You can try this

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,Bundle     savedInstanceState) {
       View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_layout, container, false);
       TextView txt = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.Zipcode);
       Typeface font = Typeface.createFromAsset(getActivity().getAssets(), "fonts/customfont.ttf");
       txt.setTypeface(font); 
       return v;
}
```

with this you can have the context in the scope of the fragment and get the view and the assets

Comment: This worked. Also `onCreateView` must return a view which your code does not. `return v;` should be at the bottom.

Comment: My app is FC for some reason :/

Answer (score 0):

Define typeface in yourViewHolder class`

```
Typeface customFontBold= Typeface.createFromAsset(getActivity().getAssets(),"fonts/JosefinSans-Bold.ttf");
```

like this.

Answer (score -1):

> My Simple code is change method call "context" in
>   the fragment with "getContext();
>   //is getContext and getActvity same in fragment??

```
**result**.setText("Value Expenses = " +expenses);
Typeface supercell = Typeface.createFromAsset(**getContext()**.getAssets(), "fonts/Supercell.ttf");**
**result.setTypeface(supercell);**
}catch (Exception e) 
{
Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "SUCCEED, VALUES RESULT", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
.show();
}
break;
```