# Initialize Typeface in a fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, fragment, typeface

i have this line :

```
Typeface font = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "fonts/Delius-Regular.ttf");
```

but the `getAssets()` parameter seems to bring some error, it is underlined with scary red lines, it says

> The method getAssets() is undefined for the type ProfileFragment

ProfileFragment is the name of my class and it extends Fragment.

**NOTE :** The font style is also on the assets folder.

Comment: getActivity().getAssets()

Comment: have you tried `getActivitiy().getAssets()....`

Comment: tnx it worked, im learning alot here haha..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You cannot get `getAssets()` from a fragment directly. You have to use  `getActivity().getAssets()` instead of using only `getAssets()`.

---

Use this

```
Typeface font = Typeface.createFromAsset(getActivity().getAssets(), "fonts/Delius-Regular.ttf");
```

instead of

```
Typeface font = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "fonts/Delius-Regular.ttf");
```

---

Read more about [Set custom font for Android fragments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12062309/set-custom-font-for-android-fragments)