# android: not able to set custom font

Tags: android, fonts, android-activity

I tried to set a custom font in a TextView.

Therefore I copied the otf file into `/src/main/assets/fonts` and added the following part to my onCreate within the Activity:

```
TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.profil_fullname);
Typeface tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "fonts/MavenProLight-100.otf");
    tv.setTypeface(tf);
```

But it does not work. I get no error and the app works, but the font is not the intended one. Do I have to add the asset folder to my build.gradle?!

**EDIT1:**
I changed the fontname to MavenProLight.tff (I also converted it into a truetype font). Furthermore I moved it to `src/main/assets` and builded it again. Nothing changed so far and the Logcat does not contain any problem specific warnings or debug infos.

**EDIT2:**
I found the problem! I used the design as layout within a Fragment. Therefore the onCreate of the Activity never gets called. Look at this page for more information: [Set custom font for Android fragments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12062309/set-custom-font-for-android-fragments)

Comment: It may be that Android is not able to read this type of file and create a Typeface from it. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/1430320/1207921

Comment: convert it to truetype font (.ttf)

Comment: Agreed, it may be that Android cannot read your font for some reason. Look for messages in LogCat, probably at debug or warning level.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please delete folder fonts sub folder of assets folder
and also rename mavenProLight.otf instead of MavenProLight-100.otf. then try this.

```
        TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.profil_fullname);
        Typeface tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "mavenProLight.otf");
        tv.setTypeface(tf);
```

May be get works 100%. Best of luck!

Comment: All fonts and another files must be in assets folder? This smells like a mess.

Answer (score 1):

problem is with your path /src/main/assets/fonts . place the fonts in assets/fonts folder and it will wrk :)

Comment: `src/main/assets/fonts` is perfectly fine for an Android Studio or Gradle build.